# Has anyone used the "selection preferences" provided by MKS Yacc?

Tags: yacc

Since I've gotten no answer at all to my question [Is there an alternative to MKS Yacc that supports selection preference syntax or something very similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475787/), I'll ask the more basic question:

- Has anyone used the "selection preferences" provided by MKS Yacc?

If you have, what did you use it for?  Also, does it make any sense to use it in anything other than the last position in a rule?

I have to look after a grammar which figures rules such as:

```
    TOKEN1 LPAREN non_terminal1 [^EQUAL] TOKEN2 non_terminal2 RPAREN
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, the embedded selection preference doesn't provide any value whatsoever in this context.

#### Background

MKS Yacc supports a notation which their web site calls "[selection preference syntax](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/wp/wp_lyuse.asp)". It isn't illustrated, but it consists of a token or list of tokens in square brackets with a caret (which might be optional), and it indicates that the particular token must not follow this construct, but that token is not counted as part of this rule:

```
non_terminal1:  TOKEN1 non_terminal2 TOKEN2 [^TOKEN3]
```

So, this rules says that a `TOKEN1` followed by a `non_terminal2` and a `TOKEN2` is a `non_terminal1`, unless the next token is a `TOKEN3` in which case some other rule applies.

(I'm not clear whether the bracketed item can be a non-terminal. The code I've seen using the notation always uses a token or a couple of space separated tokens, and never a non-terminal.  I'm also not clear whether the caret is required; again, all the examples I've seen use the caret.)

Comment: As of 2020-04-21, the MKS manual link is broken.  It is, however, available via the WayBack Machine (Internet Archive) at [Using MKS Lex & Yacc Effectively](https://web.archive.org/web/20150317104132/http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/wp/wp_lyuse.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonathan. at 1:30 AM I'm not prepared to try to do this myself, but whatever those rules do, they can only be shorthand for rules that could be written in something like normal BNF.  Looking at this, it appears that what the "selection preference" is doing is allowing you to express what would otherwise be several productions with one grammar rule.

I did a little digging and found [this](http://www.thinkage.ca/english/products/yay-manual.html#SelectionPreference), which confirms my supposition: what the selection preference does is lets you explicitly insert a lookahead, so that rules which would otherwise be in conflect can be disambiguated.

What I'd suggest is to think about what one of these rules would look like if re-written into yacc or straight BNF.  I suspect it will turn out something like

```
TOKEN1 LPAREN non_terminal1 MULT TOKEN2 non_terminal2 RPAREN
TOKEN1 LPAREN non_terminal1 DIVIDE TOKEN2 non_terminal2 RPAREN
TOKEN1 LPAREN non_terminal1 ADD TOKEN2 non_terminal2 RPAREN
TOKEN1 LPAREN non_terminal1 SUBTRACT TOKEN2 non_terminal2 RPAREN
TOKEN1 LPAREN non_terminal1 EXP TOKEN2 non_terminal2 RPAREN
TOKEN1 LPAREN non_terminal1 MOD TOKEN2 non_terminal2 RPAREN
...
```

So that the overall effect is to take one rule for every operator *except* equal, the `[^` notation being common in the various Bell Labs languages for something like the complement of a set.

Comment: Note that the URL is broken as of 2020-04-21, and the WayBack Machine (or Internet Archive) has no record of the page.  I did, however, find a [Yay Summary](https://www.thinkage.ca/gcos/expl/yay/expl.html) and the [Yay Manual](https://www.thinkage.ca/gcos/expl/yay/manu/manu.html) via a Google search.

Comment: It doesn't look like the MKS YACC manual is available outside the MKS Toolkit any longer. https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/rn/relnotes_ly341.htm#docs

Comment: IBM has it. Did they acquire MKS? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4.bpxa600/bpxa6127.htm

Comment: I've seen it in a zSeries manual — probably the one you've just linked to.  I also found the other link in the WayBack Machine (2016 — many of the later versions, and from 2017 onwards consistently, do not link to the material).  It is still available from MKS — or its successor.  The [MKS Software](https://mkssoftware.com/) site is still present and contains info about MKS Toolkit (and hence MKS Yacc), but the company owning it is [PTC](https://ptc.com/).  AFAIK, they are still independent of IBM, but IBM did some sort of deal with them to get MKS Yacc available on the zSeries mainframes.

Comment: I guess that's the problem with 11-year-old links.